# How can we prevent duplicate key attacks on digital signatures

Tags: public-key, signature, attack

A limitation digital signatures is that for a given signature **σ** of a message **m** corresponding to a public key **pk**, an adversary could generate a **pk'**, **sk'** that produces a signature **σ'**  for **m**, such that **σ'  = σ**. How can we create a signing function and verification function that is resistant to this attack?

Comment: Actually, your question lacks an important aspect in cryptography; What is the power of the adversary? polynomially bounded or not bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dan Boneh and Victor Shoup's *A Graduate Course in
Applied Cryptography*:

> it is quite easy to immunize a
> signature scheme against DSKS attacks: the signer simply attaches his or her public key
> to the message before signing the message. The verifier does the same before verifying the
> signature. This way, the signing public key is authenticated along with the message (see
> Exercise 13.5). Attaching the public key to the message prior to signing is good practice and
> is recommended in many real-world applications.

Answer (score 3):

DSKS attacks belong to a class of attacks on signature schemes that break « exclusive ownership ». A property that is not guaranteed by standard EUF-CMA security.

One solution to this is the [BUFF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1525) construction. It is very much similar to what Boneh-Shoup recommends. In short, given a signature key pair $(sk,pk)$ to sign $m$, first compute $h = H(m,pk)$, then $\sigma = Sig(sk,h)$. The signature is $(h, \sigma)$. Verification compares the hashes and validates the signature.

The BUFF construction offers more features than exclusive ownership; the paper talks about them.

Comment: Interesting, but it increases the signature size. Aren't $\mathsf{Sig}(sk,(pk\mathbin\|m))$ or $\mathsf{Sig}(sk,(pk\mathbin\|H(m)))$ fine against DSKS attacks, with no size penalty?

Comment: @fgrieu, yeah that works too. I guess I failed to convey that this was an was an alternative with further features.

Comment: Actually, this still doesn't prevent the attacker as OP requested since the OP did not restrict the power of the adversary. In this case, they still can find such $(pk,pk)$ pair if possible.

Comment: @kelalaka, it’s true that an unbounded adversary can recover the key pair itself. I think it’s fair to interpret the question as considering bounded adversaires as seems appropriate to signatures and DSKS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that kind of attack is only possible when you have a "formula" for calculating signature from private key and message hash that can be inverted - choose a signature and a message and calculate the private key. Various variants of Schnoor's and ElGamel signature schemes has this property.

The easiest solution I can think of is to use a hash-based signature such as some variant of the XMSS, LMS, and SPHINCS signature scheme.