# Why is domain separation required?

Tags: hash, context-string

I understand that domain separation in hashing is important, but I'd like to understand more clearly why and what are the risks involved.

- What is the theoretical justification for requiring domain separation?
- What are examples of schemes/protocols that can be broken if domain separation is not used?
- How can one evaluate whether the lack of domain separation is an issue or not? (e.g. Ed25519 does not use it, why is that acceptable?)

Comment: EdDSA as specified in IETF RFC 8032 include variants for both curves that include domain separation info.

Comment: Similar [Q](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/99952/36960) for DSS.

Comment: I made an [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/106180/555) to DannyNiu's [older question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/99952/555). It should (at least partially) answer the first two points, and give vague clues for the third (but it does not formally answer that, other than by: no context is needed if we follow the "one usage, one key" principle).

Answer (score 4):

On the first question,the following paper: ["Separate Your Domains: NIST PQC KEMs, Oracle Cloning and Read-Only Indifferentiability"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/241) touches upon the usefulness of domain separation especially for formalizing oracle cloning (making multiple random oracles out of a single one).

On the second question, the paper discusses vulnerabilities due to lack of domain separation in NIST post-quantum KEMs.